# Widget on corner QTabBar is not in corner

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, qtabwidget

I have a pushbutton to add a tab in a QTabWidget. But when I change the button's size, it's not in the corner anymore. So how can I bring it to the corner like in the first picture?

Not change size:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/10NJy.png]

Change size:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA4Zp.png]

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class PlaylistTable(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlaylistTable, self).__init__()
        self.playlistTable = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.playlistTable.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.playlistTable.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.playlistTable.setLineWidth(0)
        self.playlistTable.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.playlistTable.setVerticalScrollMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.playlistTable.setHorizontalScrollMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.playlistTable.setShowGrid(True)
        self.playlistTable.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.playlistTable.setWordWrap(True)
        self.playlistTable.setCornerButtonEnabled(True)
        self.playlistTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)


class CustomTabWidget(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    """Tab Widget that that can have new tabs easily added to it."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # Tab Bar
        self.tab = QtGui.QTabBar()
        self.setTabBar(self.tab)

        # Properties
        self.setMovable(True)
        self.setTabsClosable(True)

        self.plusButton = QtGui.QPushButton("+")
        self.plusButton.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(22, 22))
        self.setCornerWidget(self.plusButton)

        # Signals
        self.connect(self.plusButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.addTab)
        # self.tab.plusClicked.connect(self.addTab)
        self.tab.tabMoved.connect(self.tab.moveTab)
        self.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.removeTab)

    def addTab(self):
        string = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8("Playlist")
        tab = PlaylistTable()
        super(CustomTabWidget, self).addTab(tab, string)


class AppDemo(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppDemo, self).__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, -1, 0, -1)

        self.playlist_manager = CustomTabWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.playlist_manager)

        self.playlist_manager.addTab()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.show()
# end class AppDemo


def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = AppDemo()
    w.setWindowTitle('AppDemo')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason is this, from QTabWidget Documentation:

> The geometry of the widget is determined
>   based on the widget's sizeHint() and the style().

If you print the `sizeHint()` of the QPushButton you will see that **width** never goes below a certain value.

I've found an alternative is to use a `QToolButton` which can do everything (even more) a QPushButton does.

```
self.plusButton = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
self.plusButton.setText("+")
```